# Media keys partially working in Cinammon

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, cinnamon, media-buttons

Running Cinnamon (3.6.7), my keyboard's media keys are only partially working.

The volume up/down and mute keys work fine (they seem to be captured by the system) but the play/pause and next/previous keys do not do anything.

The curious part is that in the OS keyboard settings menu, under shortcuts, they are all mapped correctly (e.g. `Next track`: <kbd>Audio next</kbd>). Re-mapping them doesn't help, however mapping them **with modifier keys** (e.g. `Next track`: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Audio next</kbd>) works fine.

How can I get Cinnamon to understand these media keys without needing a modifier?

Comment: It seems that by default your laptop is replacing the functionality of your F1-F12 keys with these hotkeys such as volume, mute, etc. but some of the mappings are not properly detected. The reason that adding a modifier works is because your laptop is actually sending it a different key command, such as Alt+F3 instead, since most laptop manufacturers don't use the special use when combined with a modifier key like Alt/Ctrl/Shift.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning in the question, but this is not a laptop, and the keys are dedicated. I have 12 F-keys that have no other possible purpose (unlike one would see on a laptop) and additionally I have 4 dedicated media keys. I also have no 'Fn' key that would normally be used.  I'm also able to press the raw key in the shortcuts config screen and have it detected correctly, which makes me believe the OS can read the key fine.